# Soundcloud API: Change redirect URI of app

Tags: soundcloud

I've lost access to the domain that my app's redirect URI points to. In the interface (https://soundcloud.com/you/apps) there doesn't appear to be an edit button or any way to change my redirect URI. What do I have to do in order to change it.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: After looking at the Disqus on the blog post the announced the new process for getting a Soundcloud app, a lot of people seem to and as of right now, there isn't a way to change it. Most people are trying to just get new API keys which sucks and takes a long time and there's always the chance that you'll get denied anyway. If the app you're making is just for personal use, I think for now I'd recommend changing the hosts file on your local machine to point to the correct IP address for the redirect.